# Catch Android MediaPlayer errors

Tags: android, media-player

I want to catch MediaPlayer errors like this:

```
01-03 21:03:08.797: E/MediaPlayer(9470): error (1, -2147483648)
```

or this

```
01-03 20:52:48.859: E/MediaPlayer(8674): error (1, -1004)
```

Which exception do I need to catch? I tried it with

```
    try {
        mp.start();
    }

    catch (IllegalArgumentException e){Log.d(TAG, "error1");}
    catch (IllegalStateException e) {Log.d(TAG, "error2");}
    catch (Exception e){Log.d(TAG, "error2");}
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me which exception I have to catch?

Comment: Did you fix the error (1, -2147483648)? If yes, can you please share the solution with me? I am having the same error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to implement android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener in your Fragment or Activity.

```
/*
     * Called to indicate an error. Parameters
     * 
     * mp the MediaPlayer the error pertains to what the type of error that has
     * occurred: MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED extra an extra
     * code, specific to the error. Typically implementation dependant. Returns 
     * True if the method handled the error, false if it didn't. Returning
     * false, or not having an OnErrorListener at all, will cause the
     * OnCompletionListener to be called.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extras) {

        return true;
    }
```

When you create your MediaPlayer make sure you call

```
mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
```